# How do to a 3-pane display with only 2 active at the same time (à la Gmail)

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I'm writing an app that would look like gmail. In fact I want to have 2 panes active on the screen, exactly like in the Honeycomb gmail app.

My main layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="org.bicou.newsreader.SubscriptionsList"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_left_list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_middle_content" android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_right_content" android:layout_weight="8"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `SubscriptionsList` Fragment, upon loading, populates the `fragment_middle_content` framelayout with another fragment.

When I do something in the second fragment, I want to :

- hide `fragment_left_list`
- put `fragment_middle_content` to the left
- show `fragment_right_content` with a 3rd fragment.

However, I don't know how to do this. As in the XML layout above, you can see that the 3rd frame layout is hidden (visibility == gone). So when I do something in the 2nd fragment, I have :

```
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        // Hide the left pane
        SubscriptionsList sl = (SubscriptionsList) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_left_list);
        ft.hide(sl);

        // Show the right pane
        OneItem oi = OneItem.newInstance(mEntries.get(position));
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_right_content, oi);
        ft.show(oi);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_right_content).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
```

This works once. When I push back, the back stack restores the fragment transactions but doesn't hide the 3rd fragment.

I know I don't have the right approach but I'm not yet comfortable with 3.0 programming APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that works :

- I made the 3rd fragment actually a `<fragment>` in XML.
- when the app starts, I add a transaction that hides it
- when I click an item, I show it & replace it with the content I want to display

The result is kind of sluggish, but I think it is because it initializes a webview in the contents while displaying the transition. I'll find a way to make this smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with overriding the back button int the main activity. I am using 1 fragment following by 2 FrameLayouts in the main layout xml file.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        View partlarFrame = findViewById(R.id.partview_fragment);
        if(partlarFrame != null && partlarFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        {
            partlarFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
            ft.show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tutlist_fragment));
            ft.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.partview_fragment));
        ft.commit();
        return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```